# Is “I is free” grammatical

Tags: grammaticality, verb-agreement, be

I heard the sentence “I is free” in the movie *Django Unchained*. But is that really a well-formed sentence grammatically? Could I use it myself in regular conversation?

Comment: Do you mean something like "Rooms G, H, J and K are occupied, do you have any others?". "I is free." ;-)

Comment: As much as I love Tarantino I would definitely not recommend using *Django* as a point of reference for what should or should not be used in casual conversation...

Comment: Arguably even though [Sterling Archer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterling_Archer) often struggles to find [le mot juste](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mot+juste), the show does make a point of calling attention to some of the quirks of English.

Comment: [Is You Is Or Is You Ain't (My Baby)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m7M4thNT_EY)

Comment: Have you tried to search for usage of this structure? “How is it that you can stand there and tell me I is free and still tell me what I got to do?" (Where? Who was that?) "Yay, I is free!  School's over, as well as my demo reel and portfolio. Finished backing up junk sitting on the hard-drives." (Huh?)

Comment: “I is free!” is perfectly grammatical if your name is Dobby. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

[African-American Vernacular English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English). Example:

> Porgy, I’s yo’ woman now, I is, I is! An’ I ain’t never goin’ nowhere ’less you shares de fun.
>   —*lyrics of the song “Bess, You Is My Woman Now”, from the musical* [Porgy and Bess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porgy_and_Bess)

Comment: I've always considered Porgy and Bess an opera rather than a musical.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, no. The conjugation of the verb "to be" in the Present tense is

> I   ***am*** 
>   you  *are*
>   he   *is*
>   we   *are*
>   you  *are*
>   they *are*

You do hear *I is* in certain dialects, you will quite often hear it in Rap and Reggae music for example, but I would not recommend using it in conversation in most situations.

Comment: In conversation literacy is irrelevant. When you're talking, it doesn't matter whether you can read, just like when you're walking, it doesn't matter whether you can drive a car.

Comment: @JohnLawler fair enough. How would you then describe someone who does not know how to speak properly? _Inarticulate_ means they cannot express themselves well and does not imply grammatical errors.

Comment: It usually applies to people who can't read/write grammatically, and/or aren't familiar with *literary works*, but [illiterate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/illiterate) *2b: Violating prescribed standards of **speech** or writing*.

Comment: Why did you put "dialects" in quotation marks? IFAIK, *I is* is very common in AAVE, which certainly is a dialect without any need for quotation marks...

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան  What is "AAVE"? and what is "IFAIK (as distinct from "AFAIK"?

Comment: @TrevorD: IFAIK is a typo for AFAIK, obviously. AAVE stands for African American Vernacular English.

Comment: @ArmenԾիրունյան  Thanks. I seriously wasn't sure whether "IFAIK" was a typo, a dialectal change, or some other meaning.

Comment: "Is Far As I Knows".